# Can I add buttons to jQuery "alert"?

Tags: jquery

Can I add buttons to jQuery "alert"? I want to use the alert box like the confirmation box. I need to have 2 button on the alert, if user click yes, the data of a person will be delete. If click no, then the alert will be close.

Comment: if i click No, the data will be deleted too......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using "JQuery UI" (a library written in javascript using another library named JQuery)  you can use this code:

```
    $('body').append('<div id="yesno_dialog" title="Yes Or No"><p>Do you wish to Yes or to No</p></div>');
    $("#yesno_dialog").dialog({
        title: "Yes or No",
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes" : function () {
                alert("You chose yes.. now let's do something else here");
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(this).remove();
            },
            "No" : function (){
                alert("You chose no.. now let's do something else here");
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(this).remove();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

But you probably just need to return the value from confirm

```
    return confirm("Are you sure");
```

Answer (score 7):

`alert()` is a JavaScript function and has ***nothing*** to do with jQuery.

You probably want the [`confirm()` prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm) (which again, is JavaScript, not jQuery).

```
var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?");

if (result) {
    // Delete the user
} else {
    // Do nothing; they cancelled
}
```

For more advanced popups, you could emulate your own popup using "model windows"; plenty exist if you search on the Internet.

Comment: now i click ok and cancel both buttons will still delete the data, what i wish to have is when i click ok it will delete, and when i click the cancel it will close the pop up and stay at the parent page... what should i type in the code.. can u please show me the complete one? i new to programming ... thank you very much

Comment: @0070: See my updated answer. I'm not sure *how* you delete the customer in your scenario, so you'll have to code it yourself, but the placeholder is there.